# Getting special characters while reading a csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a space separated `csv` file. I am trying to read using following method:

```
$file = fopen('/var/www/html/my.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file,0,"\t")) !== FALSE) {
      $header_count = 0;
      // $final_data = array();
      if ( $count == 0 )
      {
        foreach ($line as $data) {          
            $header[$header_count] = $data;
            $header_count++;
        }
      }
      else
      {
            // print_r($line);
        foreach ($line as $data) {          
            $final_data[$count-1][$header[$header_count]] = $data;
            $header_count++;
        }

      }
      $count++;
    }
```

The file looks like:

```
id  created ad
410699345585    11:12:29+05:30  ag:6061734588280
...
```

But, the reading output gives:

```
 ["��id"]=>
```

as id index. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check character set at time of create csv.

Comment: So, there is some issue while creating the csv file?

Comment: Might be in your case actually i have faced same issue but it was due to problem of creation.

Comment: I am facing same issue. didn't find any solution yet.